# Physical Memory and Virtual Memory data allocation behavior

Tags: hardware, computer-science

Im interested in understanding how a computer allocates variables for physical memory vs files in virtual memory ( such as on a hard drive ), in terms of how does the computer determine know where to put data. It almost seems random in both memory storage types, but its not because it simply can't put data at a memory address or sector (any location) of a hard drive that's occupied or allocated for another process already. When I was studying how Norton's speed disk ( a program that de-fragments files on hard drives ) on my old W95 system, I noticed from the program's representation of hard drive's data ( a color coded visual map of different data types, e.g. swap files were always first at the top.), consisting of many files spread out all over the hard drive with empty unused areas. In addition some of these areas, I saw what looked like a mix of data and empty space showed a spotty pattern. I want to think its random for that to happen. Like wise, when I was studying the memory addresses of a simple program I wrote in C, I noticed that each version of my program after recompiling it after changes - showed different addresses for segments and offsets. I was expecting the computer to use the same address when I recompiled it. Sometimes the same address would be used, other times it was different. Again, I want to think its random also for memory locations to be chosen by programs. I thought that memory allocation or file writing was based on the first empty space available, written in a contiguous manner.

So my question is, I want to know how and what is it in the logic works of a common computer, that decides where it writes its data in such a arbitrary manner for either type of location (physical RAM or Dynamic )? What area of computer science  (if not assembly language) would I need to study that would explains this, almost random behavior?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [virtual memory and TLB (translation lookaside buffer)](http://alasir.com/articles/cache_principles/tlb_virtual_memory.html) or [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

It is not trivial to implement virtual memory and paging. The performance of your whole system depends on it. If it's not done properly your system will [thrash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

It is early morning here so Wikipedia will have to do for now: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer

**EDIT**:

Those coloured spots you saw in your defrag were chunks on your HDD. Each chunk is of some specified size. Depending on how fragmented your HDD is, you might have portions of your HDD that look like this:

> ```
> *-*-***-***-*
> ```
>
> where * means full, and - means empty

This (above) could be part of one application/file or multiple files; I will assume one file is split across those to simplify my example. At the end of each * there is a pointer to the next location where the next * chunk is (this is called a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)). The more fragmented your HDD is (or memory) the more of these pointers to next chunk you will have. This in turn uses more space for next pointers instead of using space for data and the result is more overhead when reading that data. If this is a file on disk, you will have multiple seeks (which are bad because they're slow) if your data is not grouped together (locality principle). When you use defrag, it moves and groups all chunks together (as best as it can).

> ```
> *-*-***-***-*
> ```
>
> becomes
>
> ```
> *********----
> ```

The OS decides paging and virtual memory addressing (and such). TLB is a hardware (a cache) that aids this process (it maps physical memory to virtual memory addresses for fast look up). The CPU communicates with the TLB via [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)

> **To answer your questions**
>
> - You should study operating systems.
> - Yes the locations where to place your files on HDD are decided by the OS. If you deleted a file and download it again, there is no guarantee it will be placed in the same location-most likely not.
>
> A nice summary of all these components and principles I mentioned here work: [Click Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820165031/http://web.mst.edu/%7Eercal/284/slides-1/CHAP8.ppt). It's a ppt with slides from a Real Time Operating Systems book (if I'm not mistaken the same exact one I used)

Comment: I thought paging was gone when flat memory model superseded segmented memory types

Comment: the programmer is provided with what feels like a flat memory space, but it is not flat.  In particular multi tasking/threaded systems where an MMU is used to give the appearance of the same memory model for every application (Linux and Windows are two examples) on top of what appears to be a flat memory space to the operating system.

Comment: What about on Apple Computers, do they use a different method that is esoteric to their brand for memory allocation and file mapping or do they copy an idea similar to Linux and Windows ( speaking in terms before Apple adopted Linux into their OS )?

Comment: @kjwilliams they all must use some sort of linked list to split files across memory blocks

Answer (score 0):

Something broader and directly from computer science would be a linked list. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Imagine if you had a linked list and simply added items to the end, these items might live linearly in memory or disk or whatever somewhere.  But as you remove some items in the middle of the list by having say item number 7 point at item number 9 eliminating item number 8.  As with memory allocation for allocs or virtual memory or hard drive sector allocation, etc how fast you fragment your storage has to do with the algorithm you use for allocating the next item.

file systems can/do use a link list type scheme to keep track of what sectors are tied to a single file.  it is fast and easy to use the link list but deal with fragmentation.  A much slower method would be to have no fragmentation but be constantly copying/moving files around to keep them on linear sectors.

malloc() allocation schemes and MMU allocation schemes also fall under this category.  Basically any time you take something, slice it up into fractions and put a virtual interface in front of those fractions to give the appearance to the programmer/user that they are linear.  Malloc() (not counting the virtual memory via the MMU) is the other way around allocating a number of linear chunks of those fractions to meed the alloc need, and having an alloc/free scheme that attempts to keep as many large chunks available, just in case, a bad malloc system is one where you have half of your memory free but the maximum malloc that works without an out of memory error is a malloc of a small fraction of that memory, say you have a gig free and can only allocate 4096 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't a linked list defeat the purpose of having random access memory whether its in physical RAM or platter system such as common hard drive? When I think of a linked list, its falls under the same way magnetic tape storage (reel-to-reel, cassette tapes, VCR tapes, and etc of the kind), where you create a path and distance in memory that you cant jump ahead , you must instead follow to get to the memory destination .

Comment: why do you think they have defrag tools for hard disks?  to reduce the number of times the heads have to keep going back and forth across the platters.  Even with a virtual memory system, when you want to access memory at some address, it has to go through a linked list/directory of tables at some other physical addresses, so it knows where the physical address(es) is(are).  These tables have their own cache to make this faster but you still have to push down through one level linked to another, to convert virtual to physical.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat32#FAT32  FAT12,16,32, the root of the need for the defag tool.  The entire disk is broken up into chunks, and maintained in a table the FAT, file allocation table.  read about it at wikipedia, the first paragraph or so tells the story.  directory entry points at the first cluster in the fat, and that entry points at the next and the linked list continues till you hit the end of the chain.  This is also why you get orphaned file fragments when you get corruption in some part of the disk (directory structure or fat itself).

Comment: remember be it a disk or memory the concept of random access is from the programmers viewpoint, or at least above one level of programmers viewpoint, below that magic line though, be it a combination of software and hardware or all hardware it is not flat, or linear or one high level request turns into one low level access.  Everything is broken into manageable chunks and some scheme is used to keep track of who owns what chunk and what order they are used.